# ThinkPad with Ubuntu Disk Space Issue

Tags: disk, minecraft

My son has a laptop for homework and Minecraft and when he tried to launch Minecraft after school today, he got this message....anyone able to translate and give me some idea of what I might be able to do?  Thanks

Failed to download file.
Name: 1.17.json
URL: https://launchermeta.mojang.com/v1/packages/dc07b2e194e5a7e6e6f6dd54a7ace9e66238c30b/1.17.json
Error details: No space left on device
Couldn't write to file
Filename on disk: 1.17.json
Path: /home/seek/.minecraft/assets/indexes/1.17.json
Exists: File

Comment: The hard disk is full pretty clear message.

Comment: And how do we go about making space on it?  On my work laptop I used to do something called defrag...is that worth doing (if I can work out how), or something else?  Any advice welcomed

Comment: Defrag in no way frees up space and that is windows. You need to find what has filled the drive.